# Error using mPDF with non-core font option

Tags: php, mpdf

I downloaded v6.0 of mPDF and found an example to get me started. If I use this:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','LETTER','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0,'landscape');
```

it works (at least, I get the PDF but it's not in landscape format). If, however, I use this:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('','LETTER','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0,'landscape');
```

so as to eventually use ttf fonts that I want to be included in the PDF I get this error:

> 'Can't open file
> /test_project/php/mpdf/ttfontdata/dejavusanscondensedB.GSUBGPOStables.dat'

I've not added any custom fonts to the ttfonts folder, and the .css file referenced does not specify any fonts. I see that the ttfontsdata folder is empty but is writable.

Here's the example I found that I'm testing out:

**pdfTest.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){   
   $('#fileContents').val(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
   
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>9am</th>
                <th>10am</th>
                <th>11am</th>
                <th>12am</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <td colspan="2">Geography</td>
                <td>Math</td>
                <td>Art</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <td colspan="3">Gym</td>
                <td>Home Ec</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
        <form action="php/dwnldToPDF.php" method="post">
        
                <div style="display:none;" >
                  <input type="text" name="fileContents" id="fileContents" value=''/>
                  <input type="text" name="fileName" id="fileName" value='mySitePage.pdf'/>
                  <input type="text" name="css" value='style.css'/>
                  
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="createPdf" value="Download PDF"/>
       </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**dwnldToPDF.php**

```
<?php
$fileContents = stripslashes($_POST['fileContents']);
$css = $_POST['css'];
$fileName = $_POST['fileName'];

//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");

//setup
$mpdf=new mPDF('','LETTER','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0,'landscape'); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
// LOAD a stylesheet
$stylesheet = file_get_contents($css);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    
// The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text
$mpdf->WriteHTML($fileContents);
$mpdf->Output($fileName,'D');
//I: send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if available. The name given by filename is used when one selects the "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.
//D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by filename.
//F: save to a local file with the name given by filename (may include a path).
//S: return the document as a string. filename is ignored.
exit;
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
//==============================================================
?>
```

**style.css**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
```

table {
border: none;
}
th, td {
border: none;
background-color: #dddddd;
padding: 5px;
width: 100px;
}

Note that I am unable to use mPDF v7 as that requires Composer to deploy and I've yet to get that working (I've installed Composer and the mpdf package, but I can't get it to work in php file yet).

Comment: Is your /test_project/php/mpdf/ttfontdata directory writable for the user running PHP? When so, mPDF should generate font .dat files automatically if they are not available. Can you provide more details about the error apart from the error message (file, line)?

Comment: The mpdf/ttfontdata is indeed writable, and now I see it filled with a whole whack of .dat files that just showed up today as I was repro'ing this to get you the info you requested. And guess what? No error. Ugh. There is no reason why it's any different today than when I logged this - I haven't changed anything.